# How can I set up my winform button so that I can either click the button or press enter

Tags: c#

I have some buttons on a winform that I would like to have the option of either clicking the button or press enter but I cannot figure out how to do it.  Is it even possible?

Comment: It's default behaviour. You can click by mouse or press enter or press space.

Answer (score 8):

Set the `AcceptButton` property on your form to the button you want.

Comment: So you can only do it with one button per form?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie yes -- how else would the form know what button you meant?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a button the default button on a form you should set the property **AcceptButton**.
In this way, if another control in your form has focus, pressing enter will close the form.

The same process is valid if you want a cancel button (a button connected to the **Escape** key). This time you set the **CancelButton** property on the form.

Comment: I will keep the CancelButton info in mind for future reference.  Thank you.